# Area between the curve and x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area between the curve $y={2\over x-1}-1$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $[2,4]$

Would this solve the question $\int_{2}^4( {2\over x-1}-1)dx$ ?

So...

$[2\ln(x-1)-x+c]_2^4$ would be incorrect because the curve would be below the x-axis for $3$ to $4$

Comment: But be cautious, the function is negative on $(3, 4]$.

Comment: Hi stuart, I see you have already asked a few questions, most of which have received good answers. If you're satisfied with an answer, you can not only upvote it, but also *accept* it by using the little check mark right below the up- and downvote arrows. This lets whoever answered your question know that you are indeed satisfied with the answer, and it helps people spot questions which still need more attention. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\int_{2}^4 \bigg({2\over x-1}-1\bigg)dx$$

Yes it will, you are right

$$=\underbrace{\int_{x=2}^{x=3}\int_{y=0}^{y=\frac{2}{x-1}}\,dy\,dx}_{=\ln(4)}-\underbrace{\int_{x=3}^{x=4}\int_{y=\frac{2}{x-1}}^{y=0}\,dy\,dx}_{=-\ln\big(\frac 9 4\big)}$$

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{=\ln(4)+\ln\big(\frac 9 4\big)\approx0.575}}$$

Comment: perhaps your limits $1\to 3$ in the first part are wrong you may check if you don't mind

Comment: it's correct, I will put more info

Comment: Direct integration on the whole interval is not correct.

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comment, you should divide the interval $[2, 4]$ to two parts,
\begin{align*}S = &\int_2^3\left(\frac{2}{x - 1} - 1\right) dx \;{\color{red} -}\int_3^4\left(\frac{2}{x - 1} - 1\right)dx \\
= & \left[2\log(3 - 1) - 2\log(2 - 1) - 1\right] - \left[2\log(4 - 1) - 2\log(3 - 1) - 1\right] \\
= & 4\log 2 - 2\log 3.
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

Essentially finding the area under in the curve is integrating. So in short, yes, that would solve the question.